# No File writen down to HDFS in flink

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-flink

I'm trying to consume kafka by flink and save the result to hdfs but no file was produces all the time.. and no error message raise up..

btw, it's ok to save to local file but when I change the path to hdfs, I got nothing.

```
object kafka2Hdfs {

   private val ZOOKEEPER_HOST = "ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181"
   private val KAFKA_BROKER = "ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092"

  private val TRANSACTION_GROUP = "transaction"
  val topic = "tgt3"

  def main(args : Array[String]){
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000L)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)

    // configure Kafka consumer
    val kafkaProps = new Properties()
    .... //topic infos
    kafkaProps.setProperty("fs.default-scheme", "hdfs://ip:8020")

    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), kafkaProps)
    val source = env.addSource(consumer)

    val path = new Path("/user/jay/data")

    // sink
    val rollingPolicy : RollingPolicy[String,String] = DefaultRollingPolicy.create()
      .withRolloverInterval(15000)
      .build()

    val sink: StreamingFileSink[String] = StreamingFileSink
      .forRowFormat(path, new SimpleStringEncoder[String]("UTF-8"))
      .withRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy)
      .build()

    source.addSink(sink)

    env.execute("test")
  }
}
```

I'm very confused..

Comment: <flink.version>1.7.2</flink.version>
        <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.1</hadoop.version>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there could be two things to look into:

1. Is the HDFS namenode properly configured so that Flink knows it tries to write to HDFS instead of local disk?
2. What do the nodemanger and taskmanager logs say? it could fail due to permission issue on HDFS.